# Does java cache method results?

Tags: java, methods

If i have an immutable class like this:

```java
public class MathClass {
    private final int x;

    public MathClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int calculateSomething() {
        return Math.sqrt(x);
    }

}
```

Does the jvm cache the result of calculateSomething() on the first call?
I have a more complicated calculation in the MathClass.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it

Answer (score 0):

No it does not, only the object is stored within the cache

You could use your own caching solution, such as Spring's `@Cacheable` to store method results in cache

Answer (score 0):

No, Java doesn't cache method results in general.

Some few methods of the Framework do this, but it's part of their implementation, e.g. `Integer.valueOf(int)`.

c.f. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)):

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range."

But with your implementation it would be easy to implement the "caching" by yourself: the class is immutable, that means the inputs don't change, so you can easily calculate the value on the first request and return the previously calculated value on subsequent requests:

```java
public class MathClass {
    private final int x;
    private transient boolean calculated = false;
    private transient int preCalcSomething;

    public MathClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int calculateSomething() {
        if (!calculated) {
            preCalcSomething = Math.sqrt(x);
            calculated = true;
        }
        return preCalcSomething;
    }
}
```

I used the `transient` keyword here to mark that those two fields are not part of the "object state". Don't forget to exclude them from `equals` and `hashCode` calculations and maybe other state-depending methods!

If you are using an object instead of a primitive, I would use `null` as indicator for "not yet calculated" if that is a value that cannot be the actual result of the cached operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate it just once, and then return the result previously calculated.

```
    public class MathClass {
    private final int x;
    private final int result;

    public MathClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        this.result = Math.sqrt(x);
    }

    public int calculateSomething() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

The calculation will not be performed more than one time. This is not a cache but works as one in your scenario.

Comment: With this exact implementation  you wouldn't even have to store `x` as you don't use it later in the code.

Comment: Yes, @cyberbrain, you are right! I gave this example just to show you can have the original value and the result, both available in the instance. Just an example.